# Add style according to the value of x-text/html value

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I want to center my td element when the text is equals to "-". If the text is equals to something else, I want it align at the left.

How can I do that?

```
<td x-bind:style="$el.textContent == '-' ? { 'text-align': 'left' } : { 'text-align': 'center' }" x-text="format(variable)"></td>
```

Yes, I could simple replace the `$el.textContent` by `format(variable)`, but I would like to not call `format(variable)` twice.

Comment: `$el` is not reactive, so when you change `variable`, the style binding wont update itself. You need to use a different approach. Could you share some more context? What's the source of `variable`? How does the main Alpine.js component look like?

Comment: `variable` is an element from my database. The `format` function is really simple. If the variable is empty, it will return me "-" else it will return me the value of the variable.

Comment: Also, I have multiple `td` that I went to apply the same logic (they don't have the same variable, but they all call `format` which is in my alpine data component).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `variable` itself at the style binding:

```
<td x-bind:style="variable !== '' ? { 'text-align': 'left' } : { 'text-align': 'center' }" x-text="format(variable)"></td>
```

This way the style binding is reactive as well.

#### Edit:

If you really want to avoid using `variable` at the style binding, you can combine [`x-init`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init) with the [`$nextTick`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick) magic to wait until Alpine.js finishes updating the DOM, so you can grab the actual content of the cell and update the cell's style if it's just a dash. However this method is not reactive.

```
<td x-init="$nextTick(() => {if ($el.textContent == '-') {$el.style['text-align'] = 'center'}})"
    x-text="format(variable)">
</td>
```

Comment: My goal is to not repeat anything in x-text, so I don't want to call variable in my x-bind.

Comment: Can I ask why? It seems like an arbitrary constraint that prevents your goal. Furthermore `$el` is also a variable, just not reactive, so it's not suitable for use case.

Comment: It's just to make maintenance easier. If I modify the variable for another one in x-text, I will also need to modifiy the one in my x-bind.

Comment: You can also use a modern text editor that helps you refactor your code. But if you really wish to avoid using `variable`, then there's a verbose method to get the actual cell's content. See my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, since the value of my variable may change over time, it does not always work.

Comment: Then your problem cannot be solved with these constraints. You want to use the value of a variable, without accessing the variable... Just use my first, very simple recommendation and move on.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patience and your answers !